# Redirect to nested routes with different controller

Tags: ruby

I have the next nested route `redirect_to [:financier, product, section]` 
This works if I have a controller with the name of the last variable but my question is how can I change the name of the last controller and call it in a similar way? for example, the model is called document and I want to change the controller name how catalog

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the routing helpers:

```
redirect_to(other_thing_path(@financier, product, section))
```

Where those represent elements of the other path as necessary.